# Touching Eloquent model via polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel 5.7. I have two models, `Foo` and `Content`. Their relationship is polymorphic because `Content` can also be related to other models:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Content');
    }
}

class Content extends Model
{
    use LastModified;

    public function foos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Foo');
    }
}
```

I want to `touch` the `Foo` model whenever the `Content` model is updated. So I use a `LastModified` trait for the `Content` model:

```
trait LastModified
{
    protected static function bootLastModified()
    {
        static::updating(function ($model) {
            static::updateLastModified($model);
        });
    }

    protected static function updateLastModified($model)
    {
        $foos = $model->foos;
        if (count($foos) > 0) {
            foreach ($foos as $foo) {
                $foo->touch();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that `$model->foos` returns the correct `Foo` models, but with the wrong `id`s. Instead of the `Foo`'s own model id, each `Foo` has the `id` of the pivot table row. This means that the wrong `Foo` row is touched.

Comment: anything that prevents you from doing `protected $touches = ['foos']` on the content model?

Comment: Can you post the output of `dd($foos)`

Comment: This seems to be a strange unexpected behavior. Is everything else working fine with your relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has built-in functionality for [touching parent timestamps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps).

On the content model, you can add a property telling which relationships should be [touched](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps) when the given model is updated.

The following should work:

```
class Content extends Model
{
    protected $touches = ['foos'];

    public function foos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Foo');
    }
}
```

---

Edit: Since you are using a static updated event you should manually call `$model->touchOwners()` from the `static::updated`

Comment: Thanks Nicklas. I didn't mention that I am not using `touches`, because I also have a `static::updated` listener on `Foo`, which isn't triggered by a touch.

Comment: I had to use `$model->touchOwners()`, because `$this` isn't available in a static method. But it didn't work.

Comment: I'll mark your question as correct since given the limited information in my question you are right.